# Security rules for authorized writes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following security rule in firestore:

```
match /myCollection/{myId} {
        allow read, update, delete: if resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

This allows me to query for all user's documents using `where()` function. However it doesn't work for accessing a single document like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .document(myKey);
```

(I get `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions` error)

How can I structure my security rules (or change how I read a single document) to make sure that users can access only their own documents, but also allow direct access to a single doc?